# What closing a kotlinx.coroutines channel does

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

What closing a kotlinx.coroutines channel using channel.close() does and what the negative effect of not manually closing channels would be? If I don't manually close a channel will there be some unnecessary processing? Will there be a reference to the channel somewhere that prevents it from being GCd? Or does the close function just exist as a way of informing potential users of the channel that it can no longer be used.

(Question reposted from Kotlin forum https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/closing-coroutine-channels/2549)

Answer (score 49):

Closing a channel conceptually works by sending a special "close token" over this channel. You close a channel when you have a finite sequence of elements to be processed by consumers and you must signal to the consumers that this sequence is over. You don't have to close a channel otherwise.

Channels are not tied to any native resource and they don't have to be closed to release their memory. Simply dropping all the references to a channel is fine. GC will come to do clean it up.

Comment: Well, you can tie a channel to a resource with a `try`/`finally` as I did [there for BLE scanning in Android](https://github.com/Beepiz/BleScanCoroutines/blob/24c8637fcef3ace262eb0b8aae5e64dc04d16dd0/core/src/main/java/com/beepiz/bluetooth/scancoroutines/experimental/BleScanner.kt#L47), so in such cases, you should consume the channel or cancel it manually.

Comment: Does this also apply to `SubscriptionReceiveChannel`s of a `BroadcastChannel` or does the `BroadcastChannel` hold a reference to each `SubscriptionReceiveChannel`? Tried looking through the source but it only made me more confused because I saw there was some removal of `SubscriptionReceiveChannel`s from Arrays going on.

Sorry if the question is redundant but I am just paranoid about memory leaks.

Comment: It is the same. When you close a broadcast channel it broadcasts the corresponding close toke to all its subscribers.